# How to find $\lim_{n\to ∞} \Big[ \Big(1+ \frac1n\Big)^n - \Big(1+\frac1n\Big) \Big]^{-n }$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Could someone give me a hint on how to calculate this limit?

$$\lim_{n\to ∞} \Big[ \Big(1+ \frac1n\Big)^n - \Big(1+\frac1n\Big) \Big]^{-n }$$

I tried taking the logarithm, but after that what should I do with the the $-n$ that tends to $-\infty$.

Comment: Hint: $$\left(1+ \frac1n\right)^n - \left(1+\frac1n\right)\to e-1>1$$

Comment: okay then the limit tend to zero ? right ?

Comment: Yep, it indeed does.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: A more interesting question would have been proving that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2~\bigg[\bigg(1+\frac1{n+a}\bigg)^{n+a} - \bigg(1+\frac1{n-a}\bigg)^{n-a}\bigg] ~=~ a~e.$$

Comment: @Lucian. This is a really nice one to keep ! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just as Did commented, consider $$A=\Big(1+ \frac1n\Big)^n - \Big(1+\frac1n\Big)$$ and apply the binomial theorem. You the have $$A=(e-1)-\frac{1+\frac{e}{2}}{n}+\frac{11 e}{24
   n^2}+\cdots$$ Making the long division $$\frac 1A=\frac{1}{e-1}+\frac{2+e}{2 (e-1)^2 }\frac 1n+\cdots$$ and you are looking for the limit of $\frac 1{A^n}$.

Comment: Why all the extra (unneeded) terms?

Comment: *Claude*, see my comment on the main post. :-$)$

Answer (score 0):

You can write (1+1/n)^n as e due to standard limits. So the question is essentially (e-1-1/n)^-n. If you put n as -inf, you get (e-1)^-inf. any finite non zero positive integer raised to -inf is zero. Hence the answer is zero